# How to pair up uneven lists in a Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of points and the distances between the points and what I want to do is create Segments where a segment consists of a start and end point as well as the distance between the two points.

Using a simple for loop I can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> points = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
    List<Double> distances = Arrays.asList(1.5, 2.5, 3.5);

    for(int x=0; x< distances.size(); x++) {
        new Segment(points.get(x), points.get(x+1), distances.get(x));
    }
}

static class Segment {
    private String startPoint;
    private String endPoint;
    private double distance;

    public Segment(String startPoint, String endPoint, double distance)
    {
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

However is there a nice way to do the same with streams that doesn't add complexity to the code?

Comment: What code have you written to try this?

Comment: I could not find a good way to do it with streams, the only way I could do it cleanly was with the above for loop.

Comment: There is no "clean" way to do it with streams; nothing that will be better than what you have already.

Comment: I like how your lists visually align :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it with streams, you end up doing the same thing, i.e. iterate index values:

```
List<Segment> list = IntStream.range(0, distances.size())
        .mapToObj(x -> new Segment(points.get(x), points.get(x+1), distances.get(x)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is the same as:

```
List<Segment> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 0; x < distances.size(); x++)
    list.add(new Segment(points.get(x), points.get(x+1), distances.get(x)));
```

Unless `new Segment()` is very slow and can benefit from parallel processing, you haven't gained anything by using streams, and it actually runs slower.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was coming to, and in that case the Stream option is actually harder to read :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with a stream:

```
if (points.size() - distances.size() != 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
List<Segment> path = IntStream.range(0, distances.size())
    .mapToObj(x -> new Segment(points.get(x), points.get(x + 1), distances.get(x)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Does it add clarity, or obscure the function?

Comment: To me it obscures which is pretty much the same wall I was running into :(

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I agree. Your original code is clear and easy to grasp. There’s nothing intrinsically better about lambdas. (In fact, there can be a speed penalty of many orders of magnitude.) Sometimes they are succinct and easy to read, but too often they make an impenetrable mess of a for-loop that any beginner could interpret.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the others that Stream based solution are most likely harder to read, it might still be worth it to invest in them if you use them often or can benefit from applying complex processing to them.

I'll add a non-IntStream based approach, in case you can apply it here or in future projects:

```
public static Stream<Segment> zip(List<String> points, List<Double> distances)
{
    if (points == null || distances == null || points.size() - 1 != distances.size())
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    return StreamSupport.stream(new AbstractSpliterator<Segment>(distances.size(),
                                                                 Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.SIZED)
    {
        private Iterator<String> pointsIterator    = points.iterator();
        private Iterator<Double> distancesIterator = distances.iterator();

        private String           previousPoint     = this.pointsIterator.next();

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Segment> action)
        {
            if (!pointsIterator.hasNext())
            {
                return false;
            }

            action.accept(new Segment(previousPoint,
                                      (previousPoint = pointsIterator.next()),
                                      distancesIterator.next()));
            return true;
        }
    }, false);
}

zip(points, distances).forEach(System.out::println)
// Segment [startPoint=A, endPoint=B, distance=1.5]
// Segment [startPoint=B, endPoint=C, distance=2.5]
// Segment [startPoint=C, endPoint=D, distance=3.5]
```

I use `AbstractSpliterator` with the most barebone implementation and wrap it into a stream. You can implement `trySplit` fairly each here to take advantage of parallelism and optimize the spliterators performance by implementing `forEachRemaining`. I could add those if you are interested.

While this approach is certainly a bunch to read, using it is very easy as it hides the stream creation from the developer.

Note that you could use the same Iterator based technique without a stream by using a while loop.

Answer (score -2):

If not used Segment, this will be something:

```
   List<Object> results = Stream.concat(Stream.concat(points.stream().limit(distances.size()), points.stream().skip(1)),
     distances.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And maybe you'd like use class like Tuple3 provided by third library except Segment.